# ActionScript 3 dynamically call buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I've tried to access buttons in my menu. I only want to add listeners to the items that is in the XML file im loading.

The thing is, i dont know how to call a button i've named "Var1_btn" when i've got a string "Var1".

Does anyone know how to call buttons from a for-loop?

```
for each(var chapter in presentation_xml.*)
{
    chapter + "_btn".addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, traceit);
}
```

is what i came up with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you load the xml into a variable called presentationXML, it's like this:

```
for each(var chapter in presentationXML.*)
{
    this[chapter + "_btn"].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, traceit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for each(var chapter in presentation_xml.*)
{
    this[chapter + "_btn"].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, traceit);
}
```

but you could also use [getChildByName](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName()), like this:

```
for each(var chapter in presentation_xml.*)
{
    var myBtn:MovieClip = getChildByName(chapter + "_btn");
    myBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, traceit);
}
```

Here is a good post on [when to use getChildByName](http://simpleas3.com/documentation/display-list-children-properties/).

Answer (score 0):

DisplayObjectContainer::getChildByName()

Answer (score 0):

Better use chapter.toString().

The same effect, but other coder will read it ad understand, that chapter is being converted from XML to its string representation when concatenates with string literal.